# Preferences and user-specific settings

Tags: mysql

I want to ask what is the proper way of saving user preferences and user-specific settings in a database? What I have currently set up is in my users table I just keep adding columns that hold the data in question. For example whether the profile is public or private, or if users can send them profile comments and such. But this way seems so chaotic and the table looks awful. It bothers me that this may not be the correct way of doing it, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a settings table, then a "users to settings" table. Settings contains (for example) `setting_id` and `setting_name` for all the possible settings, then `users to settings` would have three fields: `user_id`, `setting_id` and `setting_value`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

`SELECT * FROM settings JOIN users_to_settings WHERE users_to_settings.user_id = :user_id`

```
setting_name | user_id | setting_value
--------------------------------------
Private      | 01      | true
Color        | 01      | blue
Rec. Newsletr| 01      | false
```

Comment: That seems like it would consume more space but looks so much better so I'll definitely convert! Thanks! :P

Comment: You're storing smaller amounts of data across more tables, so I'm not sure what the size difference ends up being.. but the little bit of extra space is well worth the ease of maintenance! Good luck!